# Можно ли в Burp suite сбрасывать ответы по домену

Tags: request, response

скажите, можно ли в burp suite как - нибудь (может, с помощью расширения) сбрасывать (как при ручном отслеживании) ответы в зависимости от домена? Например, для фильтрации рекламы.

Comment: Может быть вам подойдет это: https://portswigger.net/bappstore/fa14ac579cff4682b32f39af8d3651e7 ?

Comment: спасибо. Это расширение - не то, что мне было нужно, но я воспользовался им для написания своего.